# Mark IOS app not compatible with IOS 8? And add new app for IOS 8 and future?

Tags: ios

I have an app that IOS 8 breaks.  I've updated this app many time for free for years.  It's time to charge for an update which stupidly has to be released as an entirely new app, however I'm also going to lose support for lower versions of ios 5 and 4 at the same time.    Which brings up 2 questions..

1)  Is it possible to leave this app up for sale and mark it as NOT IOS 8 compatible?
  a) so that no one downloads it and it doesnt work properly if they have IOS 8
  b) so that it remains available for users that are on ios5 or less for which the new version of the app will not support

2) Can I alert current users that upgrade to IOS 8 of the update?

Thanks..

Comment: Why are you still trying to support iOS 4 and 5?

Comment: Im really not.. However, I guess it's more about leaving this app available so that current users can get the latest update, in the case they hadnt updated, but at the same time being able to release the new version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

"a) so that no one downloads it and it doesnt work properly if they have IOS 8"

I think its not required. If you app build with iOS 6 or iOS 7 then it will un smoothly on iOS 8 devices without any major issues. You should not cut down iOS 8 users.

Comment: in theory ;) I have experienced SOME situations (first hand and with other apps where this is not the case)

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately we can not restrict users from downloading app on latest OS. We can oily restrict them for older OS. So you have to support iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

if you compile with xcode5 and leave the BaseSDK set to 7 it should just work -- nothing to change
--  [in theory ;) I have experienced SOME situations (first hand and with other apps where this is not the case) ]

only if you go to xcode6 with the base sdk set to 8 THEN you have no way unless fixing the app

you can't say it won't run on ios6